# LDS Church view of Hebrews 6:13 and Isaiah 43:10

Tags: lds

This question is about [this article at the LDS Church website](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/ensign/1982/02/i-have-a-question/is-president-snows-statement-as-man-now-is-god-once-was-as-god-now-is-man-may-be-accepted-as-official-doctrine?lang=eng) titled **"Is President Lorenzo Snow’s oft-repeated statement—“As man now is, God once was; as God now is, man may be”—accepted as official doctrine by the Church?"** and the scriptures in Hebrews 6:13 and Isaiah 43:10.

I am interested in how their belief of God's past and our future affect how they view Hebrews 6:13 and Isaiah 43:10.

[Hebrews 6:13](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/nt/heb/6.13?lang=eng) says that

> For when God made promise to Abraham, because he could swear by no
> greater, he sware by himself,

[Isaiah 43:10](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/ot/isa/43.10?lang=eng) says that

> Ye are my witnesses, saith the Lord, and my servant whom I have
> chosen: that ye may know and believe me, and understand that I am he:
> before me there was no God formed, neither shall there be after me.

Above scriptures seem to describe God as being literally the only one in his position, with no one above him (Hebrews 6:13) nor becoming like him either before or after (Isaiah 43:10).

The article referenced in the beginning of this question discusses the doctrine expressed in the article title. It says that

> Therefore, the Church teaches many principles which are accepted as
> doctrines but which the First Presidency has seen no need to declare
> in an official pronouncement. This particular doctrine has been taught
> not only by Lorenzo Snow, fifth President of the Church, but also by
> others of the Brethren before and since that time.
>
> ...
>
> President Snow’s son LeRoi later told that the Prophet Joseph Smith
> confirmed the validity of the revelation Elder Snow had received:
> “Soon after his return from England, in January, 1843, Lorenzo Snow
> related to the Prophet Joseph Smith his experience in Elder Sherwood’s
> home. This was in a confidential interview in Nauvoo. The Prophet’s
> reply was: ‘Brother Snow, that is a true gospel doctrine, and it is a
> revelation from God to you.’” (LeRoi C. Snow, Improvement Era, June
> 1919, p. 656.)
>
> ...
>
> The Prophet Joseph Smith himself publicly taught the doctrine the
> following year, 1844, during a funeral sermon of Elder King Follett:
> “God himself was once as we are now, and is an exalted man, and sits
> enthroned in yonder heavens!
>
> ...
>
> Numerous sources could be cited, but one should suffice to show that
> this doctrine is accepted and taught by the Brethren.
>
> ...
>
> “This is a doctrine which delighted President Snow, as it does all of
> us. Early in his ministry he received by direct, personal revelation
> the knowledge that (in the Prophet Joseph Smith’s language), ‘God
> himself was once as we are now, and is an exalted man, and sits
> enthroned in yonder heavens,’ and that men ‘have got to learn how to
> be Gods … the same as all Gods have done before.’

The article concludes with

> It is clear that the teaching of President Lorenzo Snow is both
> acceptable and accepted doctrine in the Church today.

In the light of this belief that God is an exalted human, how does the LDS Church interpret Hebrews 6:13 and Isaiah 43:10?

Comment: question...how do LDS explain the first commandment? "You shall have no other gods before Me." Do they believe that so long as a new God comes "after" everything is ok!

Comment: @Adam If you really are interested in that, make that a question.

Comment: Useful input found in this answer: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/83423/54235

Comment: related: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/24058/how-does-the-lds-church-handle-verses-that-imply-there-is-no-one-like-god

Comment: @user100487 I haven't been able to find an official church position/interpretation of those scriptures.  But, if you are willing to consider an answer from the perspective of a practicing member of the church, then I'd be willing to provide my own (along with some biblical justification).

Comment: also related: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/41808/according-to-lds-teaching-does-god-have-a-god

Answer (score 2):

There are already multiple answers surrounding this doctrine. This answer summarizes them:

In regards to Hebrews verse the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints believe that the God of the Old Testament is Jesus, and there is no other like Him (savior).<sup>1</sup> Quote from linked answer:

> And it is consistent that there is no other like God. No other Gods concern us. We worship God our Heavenly Father only, and subject ourselves to His will. No other god, "[as there be gods many](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/nt/1-cor/8.5-6#5?lang=eng)," is of concern to us.

Similarly the Isaiah verse iterates a similar doctrine. Man becoming gods does not replace/reduce God, He is always our God.<sup>2</sup> See [this answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/54775/22319) which answers the Isaiah 43:10 specifically

<sub>1 [this answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/24059/22319), [Why do Latter-day Saints believe that Jesus Christ was Jehovah of the Old Testament?](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/ensign/1988/08/i-have-a-question/why-do-latter-day-saints-believe-that-jesus-christ-was-jehovah-of-the-old-testament?lang=eng)</sub>

<sub>2 [this answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/55137/22319)</sub>