# According to the doctrine of the LDS Church what is man's relationship with God

Tags: nature-of-god, lds, relationships

According to the doctrine of the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter Day Saints what is man's relationship with God?

Specifically what does the LDS church teach about God's view of man and how man should view God?

How are God and man related?

Please answer in context of scriptures in the bible and Book of Mormon that the LDS church doctrine on this pertains. Also sources from church leaders would be appreciated.

Comment: When you say God do you mean God the Father, God the Son, or God the Holy Ghost? The LDS church teaches that they are [separate beings](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/2132/1853).

Comment: LDS Article of Faith 1: "We Believe in God, the Eternal Father, and in His son Jesus Christ, and in the Holy Ghost" -- God is our Father, whom I believe IntegrityFirst is referring to. Jesus Christ is His Son, and the Holy Ghost is His messenger.

Comment: Yes I was referring to the God the Father.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like your question.  It is well thought out and sincere.  As a member of The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints, I strive to have a close relationship with my God. I will answer your questions to the best of my ability in the order they were asked.  I will refer to hymns in my answer because they often convey the doctrine simply and beautifuly.

**According to the doctrine of the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter Day Saints what is man's relationship with God?**

Although we believe God is our Father, He is our God who is just and who is merciful. If we offend our God, justice will have hold on us until we repent through the Atonement of Christ. That being said, God does not want us to fail, we were sent to earth to get what we couldn't as Spirits (a body and experience) and then work our way back and [prove our selves](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/bofm/alma/34.32?lang=eng#30). God's whole work and Glory is the "bring to pass the immortality and eternal life of man" ([Moses 1:39](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/pgp/moses/1.39?lang=eng#38)).

As a parent, I understand this concept a lot better. I have children, and I love them and I want the best for them, however, I cannot stop bad things from happening to them, nor would I want to all the time, for how would they learn?  When they are disobedient, they are punished, when they are obedient they are blessed. All children have a different relationship with their parents. One may not be so good, another better.  Our relationship with Him is what we make of it. If we ignore Him, He still loves us, but won't push His way into our lives. If we [allow him in](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/rev/3.20?lang=eng#19) we will build trust and a strong relationship with him.

**Specifically what does the LDS church teach about God's view of man and how man should view God?**

God the Father is the Supreme Being in whom we believe and whom we worship. He is the ultimate Creator, Ruler, and Preserver of all things. He is perfect, has all power, and knows all things. He “has a body of flesh and bones as tangible as man's” (D&C 130:22).

We believe that while Christ was on the earth, he was trying to teach us who God is and what He is like ([John 5:30](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/john/5.30?lang=eng#29)). The First Principle of the Gospel is to know for a certainty the character of God, who we come to know through living Christlike Life. I recommend you listen to Elder Holland's talk entitled "[The Grandeur of God](https://www.lds.org/general-conference/2003/10/the-grandeur-of-god?lang=eng)" He answers this question clearly and perfectly.

**How are God and man related?**

We believe that God is our Father, and we are His children. One of the most sung hymns in the church is ["I Am a Child of God"](https://www.lds.org/music/library/childrens-songbook/i-am-a-child-of-god?lang=eng) The lyrics to verse 1 are as follows:

> 1. I am a child of God, And he has sent me here, Has given me an earthly home With parents kind and dear. *Chorus:* Lead me, guide me, walk beside me, Help me find the way. Teach me all that I must do To live with him someday.

And "[Oh my Father](https://www.lds.org/music/library/hymns/o-my-father?lang=eng)", Only verse 1, but follow the link for more:

> 1. O my Father, thou that dwellest
>      In the high and glorious place,
>      When shall I regain thy presence
>      And again behold thy face?
>      In thy holy habitation,
>      Did my spirit once reside?
>      In my first primeval childhood
>      Was I nurtured near thy side?

Scriptures referenced in the hymns: [Romans 8:16-17](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/rom/8.16-17?lang=eng#15), [Acts 17:28-29 (22-31),](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/acts/17.28-29%20%2822-31%29?lang=eng#27)       [Psalm 82:6](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/ot/ps/82.6?lang=eng#5), [Mosiah 4:15](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/bofm/mosiah/4.15?lang=eng#14), [Doctrine and Covenants 14:7](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/14.7?lang=eng#6)

Answer (score 5):

I like to think of it this way:  A carpenter has many creations.  They make beautiful chairs, tables, cabinetry.  He gets joy from his creations.  A carpenter can also have children.  However, all of his creations he makes to support his family or for his family to use.  His true joy comes from his Children.  He gets overfilled with joy as he sees his children learn, He is proud when they overcome obstacles and he just wants them to succeed.  And more often then not, he is interested in his children becoming like him.

God is the same way.  He CREATED the earth the vegetation, the animals, but we are his children.  He created everything for the sole purpose of helping his children learn and grow.  He listens to our concerns and helps us overcome obstacles.  He is our Father and wants us to grow to attain the same level of happiness and joy that he experiences when he sees us succeed.

Comment: Welcome to C.SE. When you get the chance, please check out our [about] and specifically [How we are different than other sites](http://tinyurl.com/csedifferent). Good first answer.

Comment: I have updated the question I'm interested in sources from the lds scriptures and church leaders.